# EntityFramework IQueryable GroupBy multiple column and capture sum

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, grouping, iqueryable

I am trying to group by multiple columns and then sum up the Amount field of all the records into one record.

For example, I have three inventory records where they have the same location, type, and product. I want to return only one inventory record (an instance of EFModel.Inventory) but have the sum of Amount from all three records. However, I do not want to execute the query yet! Please examine the code below for some clarification. Is there an easy way to do that?

```
        IQueryable<EFModel.Inventory> query = GetInventoryView();
        if (searchParameters.GroupByLocation)
        {
            query = from inv in query
                    group inv by new { inv.LocationID, inv.LocationType, inv.ProductID }
                    into groupedInv
                    select groupedInv.First();
        }

        // Now, perform filtering, sorting, paging and etc. on the query
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: But .First() call will execute your query and by the end of the if statement, query will has the entity (if exists), otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Yes, you're right.. good catch!

Answer (score 0):

have you considered something like this:

where query is your initial collection.

```
IQueryable<EFModel.Inventory> query = GetInventoryView();
 if (searchParameters.GroupByLocation)
        {

var model = query.GroupBy((group => 
                                 new { LocationID = group.LocationID, 
                                       LocationType = group.LocationType, 
                                       ProductID = group.ProductID 
                                     }
                        )
                 .Select(select => 
                 new <returning object>() { 
                     total = select.Sum(total => total.{Amount Property}), 
                     LocationID = select.Key.LocationID, 
                     ...., 
                     //other properties here  
                     }); 
  //do other stuff here 

}
```

This is how I do similar stuff. Assuming I have read your question correctly.

any issues let me know. (Code hasn't been sense checked but should work)

Comment: `var model = query.GroupBy(...`

Comment: The inventory object has about 25 properties, is there an easier way?

Comment: @Amir there isn't really an easy way to do this without writing some code. But once you have it written once you can pull the code out and reuse it in other scenarios like this that work in a similar principle. The alternative is to do this on the server and then create a view, stored proc or table that has this data already worked out and then you can just query that table instead.